# Resize a Manipulate by grabbing a corner

Tags: manipulate

The following code produces an output of a Plot.

```
Plot[x,{x,-3,3}]
```

I can then resize the output by grabbing onto one of the corners of the image and dragging.

The following code produces an output of a Manipulate Plot.

```
Manipulate[Plot[x,{x,-3,3}],{a,0,10}]
```

I cannot resize the output by grabbing a corner.  The image size is fixed.  I would like to be able to change it by dragging the corner of the image with the mouse.  I realize I can program in the image size in the code above, but for convenience, I would like the ability to resize with the mouse.  Ideas?

Comment: this is probably version / OS dependent. You can resize the graphics in Manipulate output in version 9 /Windows10 and version 12/WolframCloud.

Comment: Oh no.  I have Mac OS 10.14 running Mathematica 12.  Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: try adding the option `PreserveImageOptions -> True` or the option `Deployed -> False` to `Manipulate`.

Comment: I’m sorry I misspoke.  It does allow you Resize the plot inside the manipulate.  However I’m looking to resize the entire image including the outer box that contains the slider.  In other words, I want to emulate increasing the magnification of the entire cell.

Comment: This would be beneficial as the slider would stay in good aesthetic proportion to the plot.

Comment: The option `ContentSize -> b` controls both the size of the content of `Manipulate` along with the size of its whole panel. Here b is a fixed value. One cam make it dynamic by wrapping it by another `Manipulate` statement. For example, like this: `Manipulate[
 Manipulate[Plot[a*x, {x, -3, 3}], {a, 0, 10}, ContentSize -> b], {b, 
  100, 500}]`

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do a proportional resize by dragging a corner (at least not without quite a bit of trouble). To do it programmatically, use `Magnify`

Comment: That comes closer!  However contentsize seems to only control the size of the outbox.  The image inside stays the same.  Also the size of the slider stays the same too. I’m looking for a way to change all aspects all at once so everything stays in relative proportion like resizing an image by dragging a corner.

Comment: `DynamicModule[{sz = {405, 316}},
 Pane[Magnify[
   Manipulate[Plot[x^a, {x, 0, 3}], {a, 0, 10}],
   Dynamic[First[sz]/405]
   ], AppearanceElements -> "ResizeArea", ImageSize -> Dynamic[sz]]
 ]`

Comment: That works.  thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it fit your needs?

```
magnifier[expr_] := DynamicModule[{initImageSize, imageSize, mag = 1}
  , initImageSize = imageSize = Rasterize[expr, "RasterSize"]
  ; Pane[
   Magnify[expr, Dynamic@mag],
   AppearanceElements -> "ResizeArea",
   ImageSize -> Dynamic[imageSize, {Automatic, (mag = Mean[imageSize/initImageSize]) &}]
   ]
  ]

magnifier@Manipulate[Plot[a x, {x, -3, 3}], {a, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Yes.  Thank you!

Comment: It would be nice to restrict the panel aspect ratio to that of the content.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, I also don't like it changes continuously as opposed to on release, will add that later.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to control the overall size of `Manipulate` by resizing the content and resize the control area using `Pane` with a `"ResizeArea"` button in the setting for the option `"ControlAreaDisplayFunction"`:

```
Manipulate[Plot[x Sin [a x + b], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> color],
  {a, -1, 1}, {b, {1, 2, 3} Pi/4}, {{color, Red}, ColorSlider}, 
 Method -> {"ControlAreaDisplayFunction" ->
       (Pane[#1,  ImageSize -> Automatic, ImageSizeAction -> "ResizeToFit", 
       AppearanceElements -> {"ResizeArea"}] &)}]
```

[image]

When controls are places in different areas, say with `ControlPlacement -> {Top, Left, Bottom}`, each control area gets its own `"ResizeArea"` button:

[image]

We can also use Kuba's function `magnifier` as `"ControlAreaDisplayFunction" -> (magnifier[#] &)`:

[image]

Comment: This works in version 9/windows 10. Don't know if it does in other version/os combinations.